# How do I store a random integer in a local variable in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some code here for a basic game I'm making in Python 3.x. As you can see, the local variable 'code1' creates a random two digit number between my values, for the first part of my vault's unlock code (later in game). What I want to do is store the random integer somehow so if the specific room is re-visited it will display the first outputted random number from this function and not keep changing as this would defeat the object of clue collecting.

```
def corridorOptions():
    code1 = random.randint(30,60)
    corridorChoice = input('> ')
    if corridorChoice == "loose":
        delayedPrint("You lift the loose floorboard up out its place." + '\n')
        delayedPrint("It shifts with hardly any resistance." + '\n')
        delayedPrint("There is a number etched. It reads " + "'" + str(code1) + "'")
```

Cheers guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest you add an attribute to the `corridorOptions` function that is only initialised *once* when it is created on the first call of the function

```
from random import randint

def corridorOptions():
    if not hasattr(corridorOptions, 'code'):
        corridorOptions.code = randint(30, 60)
    print("There is a number etched. It reads '{0:02d}'".format(corridorOptions.code))


corridorOptions()
corridorOptions()
corridorOptions()
corridorOptions()
corridorOptions()
```

**output**

```
There is a number etched. It reads '58'
There is a number etched. It reads '58'
There is a number etched. It reads '58'
There is a number etched. It reads '58'
There is a number etched. It reads '58'
```